# Cambiar de div dentro de un mismo html

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery

estoy haciendo una página con formularios, y quizás sea una cosa de los más fácil pero no encuentro documentación para hacerlo,

os explico, la página tiene un form a la izquierda, y quiero conseguir que rellenando el formulario me dé el resultado en un documento php que tengo dentro de otro div a la izquierda, no sé si me estoy explicando bien os adjunto un fragmento de código para que lo veáis visual:

```
<form name='datos_personales' id='datos_personales' method='POST' action="functions.php">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value='guardar_datos_personales' />
                                                        <div class="FormCreator-default js-form-container">
                                                            <div style="position: relative;">
                                                                <div class="form-input" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; width: 256px; height: 72px; display: inline-block; position: relative; background-color: transparent; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; transition: height 200ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; cursor: auto;">
                                                                    <label for="firstName" style="position: absolute; line-height: 22px; top: 38px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; z-index: 1; transform: scale(1) translate(0px, 0px); transform-origin: left top 0px; pointer-events: none; color: rgb(86, 93, 97);">Nombre</label>
                                                                    <div style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; bottom: 12px;">José</div>
                                                                    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" style="padding: 0px; position: relative; width: 100%; border: medium none; outline: currentcolor none medium; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); cursor: inherit; font: inherit; height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; margin-top: 14px;">
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <hr style="border-color: rgb(224, 224, 224); border-style: none none solid; border-width: medium medium 1px; bottom: 8px; box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; position: absolute; width: 100%;">
                                                                        <hr style="border-color: rgb(21, 148, 246); border-style: none none solid; border-width: medium medium 2px; bottom: 8px; box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; position: absolute; width: 100%; transform: scaleX(0); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
```

y quiero que se "reproduzca"  aquí:

```
    <div class="m-layout-info-group ">

                                                                        <div style="display:block;" class="">

                                                                            <h1>
                                                                             <?=$name;?>&nbsp;<?=$surname;?>
                                                                            </h1>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                            <div class="m-content-split">

                                                                                <span class="m-content-split-left"><b> Email </b></span>
                                                                                <span class="m-content-split-right m-content-mail"> <?=$email;?></span>

                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="m-content-split">

                                                                                    <span class="m-content-split-left"><b> Dirección </b></span>
                                                                                    <span class="m-content-split-right"> <?=$address;?> </span>

                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="m-content-split">

                                                                                <span class="m-content-split-left"><b> Teléfono </b></span>
                                                                                <span class="m-content-split-right"> <?=$phone;?></span>

                                                                            </div>
```

a punto que el código no está completo como podéis ver es un simple ejemplo, 
sino me he explicado bien decídmelo,

gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. La pregunta no se entiende del todo. Es imposible ver cómo queda tu página. Tampoco dices lo que has intentado. En todo caso, te recomendaría que leas un sobre CSS. Aplicando clases a tu código podrás hacer sin demasiada dificultad lo que quieres. Cosas como esta: `m-content` hacen pensar que usas algún tipo de librería como Bootstrap u otra, deberías mencionarlo en la pregunta. En tu HTML evita aplicar estilos *in line*, en los mismos elementos, la portabilidad y mantenimiento se hacen muy complicados. Son algunas recomendaciones.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por contestar, ya solucioné lo que quería hacer, cuando tenga un momento comentaré lo que hice y mi caso por si alguien lo necesita